# Windows 7 64bit driver for HP Color LaserJet 3700 PCL6 Printer

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, hp-laserjet

I'm currently using an HP Color LaserJet 3700 PCL5 Printer Driver with Windows 7 (64bit) Operating System..I suspect I need an HP Color LaserJet 3700 PCL6 Printer Driver since my PCL5 works but not correctly..I can't change from "color" to "greyscale" with the PCL5 driver..and I can't specify multiple copies for printing with the PCL5 driver..I can do all this with the PCL6 driver on another computer..however, the other computer's operating system is WinXP..HP's website is no help for downloading a Win7 driver for this printer..am I missing something??..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the PCL6 driver from here http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=315857&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=315849&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063

Failing that try Printing properties on the printer then advanced tab - Copy count you should be able to set it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the vista 64 bit driver. Vista and Windows 7 drivers are **NEARLY** the same.

Answer (score 0):

HP offers something called Universal Printer Driver. Try to use that. This should be fairly easy to set up and achieve what you need. Alternatively if you have Windows 2003 somewhere you can try to share printer thru it (or maybe even use 2003 drivers directly). I have LaserJet 3700 and my Windows 7 machines use it thru our 2003 printer server.